# "+" character causing issues in IIS URL rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the URL that I want to set a redirect to in IIS.

```
Current URL: portal/en_us/apps/app+doc

New URL: apps/newapps
```

Not working with

```
<rule name="From portal/en_us/apps/app+doc" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^portal/en_us/apps/app+doc$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain1123.com/apps/newapps" />
</rule>
```

results in a 404 error

Comment: `+` has a meaning in regexes. If you want a literal `+` to be matched, you need to escape it.

Comment: also: `+` is kinda awkward in URLs - it has a hybrid identity with space, along with %20

Comment: Tried this `+`--> `\+`.  `^portal/en_us/apps/app\+doc$` but still not working.

Comment: Is it possible to set redirect like `portal/en_us/apps/app` to `https://domain1123.com/apps/newapps` Instead of full matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to a [reference guide](http://regexstorm.net/reference), we'll see that `+` is defined as working like this:

> Matches previous element one or more times.

That means that this expression:

```
^portal/en_us/apps/app+doc$
```

Will match an entire string containing:

- portal/en_us/apps/appdoc
- portal/en_us/apps/apppdoc
- portal/en_us/apps/appppdoc
- portal/en_us/apps/apppppdoc

And so on.

To actually match a literal `+`, you need to escape it using `\`:

```
^portal/en_us/apps/app\+doc$
```

Now it is treated as a literal `+` and not interpreted as "one or more p characters".

**I have added allowDoubleEscaping**

```
<system.webServer>
     <security>
          <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
     </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried the same but still not working. `<rule name="From portal/en_us/apps/app+doc" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^portal/en_us/apps/app\+doc$" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain1123.com/apps/newapps" />
        </rule>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode the "+" character first, and then redirect.

You can use this link to code: https://www.urlencoder.org.